# Graded Trace Map

Tags: linear-algebra, trace, trace-map

Let $k$ be a field and let $V$ be a finite dimensional $k$-vector space.

Let $\Lambda_* : k \text{-vect} \rightarrow k \text{-alg}$ be the exterior algebra functor, whose target is associative $k$-algebras and whose cotarget is finite dimensional $k$-vector spaces.

There is a "graded trace map", where, for $f : V \rightarrow V$ a map of $k$-vector spaces, we can define $\text{tr}_* \left( \Lambda_* f  \right)$ as an element $\sum_{i \geq 0} \text{tr} \left( \Lambda_i f \right)(- t)^i$ of $k[[t]]$.

I'm wondering where I can read about this. I am also wondering where I can read about linear algebra like it.

Comment: This "graded trace map" is the polynomial $\det\left(1-tf\right)$, which is more or less the characteristic polynomial of $f$ ("more or less" because it is turned upside down and maybe multiplied with $\left(-1\right)^{\dim V}$). Note that you need $V$ to be finite-dimensional or $f$ to behave nicely enough, as otherwise the traces aren't well-defined.

Comment: I know this, but I would like a reference which says more about it, if that's possible.

Comment: Hmm. Representation/invariant theory texts that talk about "Molien's theorem" or "Molien series" should have something in this direction. Also look for "MacMahon Master Theorem".